# How do I securely tie a paracord between two rings?

Tags: knots, macrame

How do I securely attach two rings to each other with a paracord?

[image: attach paracord between two rings]

Comment: Hi Daniel. "Securely" for what purpose? What have you tried or found yourself? What kind of chord are you using? What does it have to do with macramé?

Comment: Will it always be under tension? Does it have to look nice? Does it matter if the cord is joined into a loop with a knot between the rings, and if so, where should the free ends end up? As it stands, you could just make a loop, joining the ends with a reef (square) knot or a fisherman's knot (double or triple allows you to leave very little sticking out). But I suspect you have something different in mind

Comment: Those are good questions. It’s to make a keychain. I will actually use smaller rings, and there will be other things attached to the rings. I would like to make it better looking than just tying knots on each ring. I don’t care how it looks between the rings as long as they are in knots or macrame. By “securely” I mean enough to not come loose but I don’t know enough about those things to be able to know perchance of coming loose. I was able to use a two strand wall knot and attach one ring to the loop but don’t know how to attach the two ends to the other ring.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a **ring hitch**. The problem is ring hitches are single lead and you have two. I would recommend making the same Sling Hitch as you did with the first ring and join the two ends of the cord somewhere in the middle. This would be the most secure way to attach the rings. Plus you can easily adjust the length between the rings this way before finishing the piece.

So what do you do with the loose ends in the middle? You will need a **bend** to join the two cords together. There are a lot of bends but the *Double Harness Bend* (illustrated below) seems like a good candidate. When drawn tight you can trim the ends off and you will have a knot that will stay tied.
[image: illustration of double harness knot]

If you want two cords to tie to the second ring you would simply use two ring hitches. Again, there are many possible knots that can be used so it would be a matter of personal taste and maybe some experimentation to get the one that works for you. However this would never be as strong as two sling hitches since that kind of knot cannot unravel.

There are lots of ways to tie things together and instead of a simple bend you may want a something more decorative. There are simply too many choices to list and making knots can get complicated. I recommend checking out **The Asheley Book of Knots** which is an exhaustive yet accessible reference on knot making.

Comment: Why does this video that says it's showing how to tie a ring hitch knot look like it's making a sling hitch? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvvN8-VLfp0